# Why the sub-Laplacian $\Delta_{sub}$ on the Heisenberg group $H^3 $ is sub-elliptic but not elliptic?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras, laplacian, heisenberg-groups

I want to know why the sub-Laplacian $\Delta_{sub}= X^2 + Y^2$ on the Heisenberg group $H^3 = \mathbb C \times \mathbb R$ is sub-elliptic but not elliptic, where $X$ and $Y$ are the left-invariant vector fields on $H$.

And what has been the same for the sub-Laplacian on the quaternionic Heisenberg group $H^7 = \mathbb H \times \mathbb R^3$, where $\mathbb H$ is the space of the quaternion.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Didn't you already ask this question? http://mathoverflow.net/questions/229958/how-to-prove-that-the-laplace-oparator-of-the-heisenberg-group-is-sub-elliptic?rq=1

Comment: Yes, but I can not do it, and want to know the case of the quaternionic Heisenberg group

Comment: Are you can detail your answer or can you please direct me to a reference ?